# Como criar script de inicialização no Debian modificando variáveis de ambiente

Tags: shell-script, linux

Preciso elaborar um script de inicialização que modifique a resolução que o Debian por padrão coloca. Atualmente tenho o seguinte shell script que faz o trabalho:

```
export XAUTHORITY=/home/giuliana/.Xauthority
xrandr --newmode "1368x768" 85.25 1368 1440 1576 1784 768 771 781 798 -Hsync +Vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 "1368x768"
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode "1368x768"
```

Nesse script é adicionada uma resolução 1368x768 que por padrão não é suportada no Debian 8. Depois disso é selecionada essa resolução. Para que funcione é necessário modificar o valor da variável de ambiente `XAUTHORITY`. O script funciona se eu executá-lo, porém quando eu utilizo o mesmo script para inicialização no boot ele não funciona. O que eu fiz para ele iniciar no boot foi:

1. Adicionei o script em /etc/init.d
2. Instalei o `rcconf`
3. Configurei o script que eu chamei de resolution para executar no boot usando o `rcconf`
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando eu faço o reboot, a resolução não é modificada. O que eu notei é que  a variável `XAUTHORITY` tem seu valor alterado igual a `/tmp/kde-giuliana/xauth-1000-_0` e não ao valor que coloco no script. Mas não sei quem está modificando esse valor. Algum entendedor do Debian poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Qual é a sua placa de vídeo?

Comment: Digitando o comando lspci | grep VGA aparece:
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)

Comment: Estou com o Fedora, que não usa essa estrutura tradicional dos scripts de inicialização, e não me lembro bem dos detalhes do Debian. Mas em princípio, para um script simples como esse que não segue o padrão dos scripts de inicialização eu colocaria em `/etc/rc.local`, embora não acho que isso seja o problema. A única coisa que me chama a atenção é o seguinte: os scripts de inicialização rodam no usuário `root`, e seu arquivo `.Xauthority` pertence ao usuário `giuliana`. Eu tentaria trocar para `/root/.Xauthority` e ver se funciona. PS. é só um chute...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Devido a drivers ou hardware bugados, a resolução do monitor pode ser detectada incorretamente. Por exemplo, o bloco de dados EDID fornecido pelo seu monitor pode estar incorreto ou uma versão desatualizada do KDE ou Xorg pode interpretá-lo incorretamente.

Como sua placa é Intel, instalar o seguinte pacote pode ajudar o sistema a detectar a resolução adequada:

```
$ sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

Reinicie e verifique se a resolução 1368x786 é listada nas configurações.

Se mesmo assim sua resolução não for detectada, você deve usar o `xrandr`, como já está fazendo. Para salvar permanentemente, edite o arquivo `/etc/kde4/kdm/Xsetup` e adicione o seu código antes da linha `initctl ... gdm`:

```
xrandr --newmode "1368x768" 85.25 1368 1440 1576 1784 768 771 781 798 -Hsync +Vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 "1368x768"
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode "1368x768"

initctl -q emit login-session-start DISPLAY_MANAGER=gdm
```

Existem outras maneiras menos vantajosas de persistir as customizações do `xrandr`, através do:

- `.profile`: é por usuário, o que significa que sua tela de login ficará com uma resolução estranha,
- `xorg.conf`: é obsoleto e deixou de ser incluído nas distros mais recentes.

Se precisar, as instruções para fazer estas modificações estão disponíveis na [wiki do Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Setting_xrandr_changes_persistently), mas recomendo o método pelo `Xsetup` que mencionei.

Comment: O pacote xserver-xorg-video-intel eu já tinha. O que funcionou foi o initctl ... gdm! Muito obrigada!